# How to prevent end users from editing a hidden input value in a Django social website

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

In a website having a "Comment" and "reply to a comment" system.
After each comment in the template, There's a "Add a reply" form which have a hidden input to carry the comment pk on its value attribute.

- How to prevent the end user from editing that hidden input value ?
- And If this is not possible, What would be the correct approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent somebody from editing the value attribute, since it's client-sided.

The better approach would be to check on the server-side whether the user is permitted to comment or reply to the given post. For example, you can check if the user is a friend of the creator of the post. If it's not, you can block the request.

Example:

```py
# models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()

class User(AbstractUser):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())
```

```py
# views.py
class CommentCreate(View):
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # retrieve the post object here
        ...

        # check if the user is a friend of the creator
        if post.creator.friends.filter(id=request.user.id).first(): # returns None if none found
            # user is a friend of the creator
            # do your stuff here
        else:
            # user is NOT a friend of the creator
            raise PermissionDenied()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Preventing the end user from editing: You can use the html input type of hidden

`<input type="hidden" value="{comment.pk}">`

Comment: You can still edit the value by inspecting the source code.

Comment: Yes obviously. – Alexander Schillemans:
the other way would be to use the name tag on the input/textarea of the comment field, 
<input name="{comment.pk}" value=""> or <textarea name="{comment.pk}"></textarea>

Answer (score 0):

since it is being rendered by a form, you can set it to read-only by doing this

```
<input type="hidden"  readonly>
```

You can read more on readonly attribute here [Read-only attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

Comment: End user can still edit its value by inspecting it.

Comment: Then you can use Django's form.py to render out your form so that way, even if end-user inspect an edit the value, the read-only field remains the same when posting to database. You can read about forms [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/).

Comment: readonly attribute doesn't prevent users from editing the input by inspecting it, it's only preventing users from editing the input directly.

Comment: I know, But when using Django forms and you set a field to read-only and it is pre-populated, even if the user inspects and removes the read-only attribute and adds a value of their own, when submitting, the user value doesn't get saved to database.